# What is the slope of this line?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, binary, integer-lattices

I have a lattice that has infinite length (directions) in $+x$ (leftwards) and $+y$ (downwards).
What is the **slope-value** of the line shown on the graph when the magnitude of the line increases?

[image]

My guess is that there is a fraction there, but I dont know how to find it.
Ok, after counting the cells of the interior rectangle of $3\times5$ I found out it might be $3/5 = 0.6$. But dunno if its correct.

Comment: What exactly is the repeating pattern?

Comment: Why are not happy just considering the ratio of the sides of your rectangle?

Comment: Ok, I tried and found $3/5 = 0.6$, but is there another fraction for this value?

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier the left edge on-bits (binary expansion) (that is iterations) of $f(2^n-1)$ in Odd Collatz function: $(3n+1)/2$ without the even results. So this is line is just some sub-section of the outputs.

Comment: Then there is definitely no way to answer from so little information. You are probably after the asymptotics of some function but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

- $\Delta x =10$
- $\Delta y =15$

then

- slope $= \tan \theta =\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{15}{10}=\frac32$

Comment: The OP shows only a small part of the line, there is no way to answer the actual question being asked.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I’m assuming that the pattern will repeat and at an infinite length the slope is equal to 3/2. I cannot see anybother interpretation of the OP.

Comment: I tried asking additional details and although the answer wasn't clear, I'm almost certain that this is not the case.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The line is a straight line. I've updated the diagram for more clarity hopefully. Gimusi is close to what I want.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy gimusi's answer is correct if the pattern repeats identically outside the visible box, which you haven't made clear.

Comment: The previous diagram was offset and not identical when repeating. I updated the diagram to show the correct pattern if it is outside the box now.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy All I can see is that you added empty columns. Would you please make a twice bigger grid just to be sure what you mean?

Comment: done. I don't think I can get more clear tonight.

Comment: wow. I just found out that it is correct. A very interesting result.